# Scrapy iterating over xpath resultset

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm Trying to scrape information about UFC events from the following site:
http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed?page=all

First, I get all rows in the table with `response.xpath('//table[@class="b-statistics__table-events"]/tbody/tr[@class="b-statistics__table-row"]')`

Next, I want to iterate over these `<tr>` Elements and extract other information. In the for loop, when I use `extract_first()` I always get the same records (coming from first table row). When I use `extract()[0]`, I get correct results.

Does anyone know the reason of these behaviour?

```
class EventsInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "events_info"

    def __init__(self):
        self.events = {}

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed?page=all'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        for event in response.xpath('//table[@class="b-statistics__table-events"]/tbody/tr[@class="b-statistics__table-row"]'):
            event_info = {'event_url': event.xpath('td[@class="b-statistics__table-col"]/i[@class="b-statistics__table-content"]/a/@href').extract_first().strip(),
                          'event_name': event.xpath('td[@class="b-statistics__table-col"]/i[@class="b-statistics__table-content"]/a/text()').extract_first().strip(),
                          'event_date': event.xpath('td[@class="b-statistics__table-col"]/i[@class="b-statistics__table-content"]/span[@class="b-statistics__date"]/text()').extract_first().strip(),
                          'event_location': event.xpath('td[@class="b-statistics__table-col b-statistics__table-col_style_big-top-padding"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
                          }

            self.events[event_info['event_name']] = event_info

        with open(f'events_data/events.json', 'w+') as json_file:
            json.dump(self.events, json_file, indent=6)
            json_file.close()

        self.log(f'Collected data for {len(self.events)} events')
```

Comment: extract_first() gives the same results as extract()[0], check it again.

Answer (score -1):

The xpath in the for loop didn't refer to previously filtered selectors and that's why it return values only from the first `<li>` element. I solved it by adding `.//` at the beginning of xpath in for loop.
For example:

`event.xpath('.//td[@class="b-statistics__table-col"]...`

instead of

`event.xpath('td[@class="b-statistics__table-col"]...`